# Why the play store prompts "no network connection" while I use reverse USB tethering?

Tags: google-play-store, reverse-tether

I used reverse USB tethering to share my laptop wired network connection, and my phone's browser works as normal, but the play store prompts "no network connection", why? How to enable it?